# Не парсит с html

Tags: php, html, синтаксический-анализ

Есть такой код

```
$text1 = 'Слен';
    $get = file_get_contents('http://orthography.morphology.ru/?text='.$text1);
 preg_match('/\<span class="misspelt">(.*?)\<\/span\>/', $get, $match);
 echo $match[0];
```

Почему то не работает. Хотя  когда я ставлю

```
echo $get;
```

Мне выдаёт страницу полностью нормально. Значит ошибка в 3-тей строчке, но я не пойму какая.

Comment: нет у вас ошибок в скрипте, скрипт выдает ваше слово. Разве что добавьте еще модификатор m для многострочной выдачи

Comment: А мне не выдаёт.

Comment: Если вы пользуетесь денвером то тогда думаю надо модификатор u

Comment: preg_match('/\<span class="misspelt">(.*?)\<\/span\>/mu', $get, $match);

Попробуйте так.

Comment: Добавьте модификатор **s** к регулярному выражению.  
**s (PCRE_DOTALL)**  
> Если данный модификатор используется, метасимвол "точка" в шаблоне соответствует всем символам, включая перевод строк. Без него - всем, за исключением переводов строк. Этот модификатор эквивалентен записи /s в Perl. Класс символов, построенный на отрицании, например [^a], всегда соответствует переводу строки, независимо от наличия этого модификатора.

Comment: По рукам бы надавал за использование регулярок для html. Неужели нет [нормальных парсеров](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) для таких целей?

Comment: В крайнем случаи если это не единственное что надо спарсить воспользуйтесь библиотекой phpQuery

Comment: @Deonis у всего есть предел разумности. В том числе и при парсинге HTML, XML и.т.п. регулярными выражениями.  
Более того: в простых случаях разумнее использовать именно регулярные выражения, как минимум из соображений производительности.

Comment: Товарищи попытки счетны

Comment: Если производительность и вправду очень важна, надо (1) отказаться от PHP, (2) перейти на поиск _строк_ (в нашем случае — `"<span class=\"misspelt\">"`).

Comment: @VladD, на сях оно бы пошустрее было на порядок, но вот пункт 2 не прокатит в скриптовых языках.  
Замер скорости регулярного выражения (его можно пооптимизировать еще, но меня и такой результат устраивает) и поиска точного совпадения:  
http://ideone.com/QXmzQ0  
Первый измеряемый кусок кода помимо эффективности еще и красивее и короче.

Comment: @ReinRaus: Это у PHP плохо со строками. Или может быть с поиском (например, всегда ищется регулярка?). Вот то же на C#: http://ideone.com/ziQVHO

Comment: @VladD, не совсем то же самое. Атомарная группировка принципиально важна.  
Почему-то не компилится форк, хотя вроде только атомарную группировку добавил:
http://ideone.com/BvQU6B

Comment: @ReinRaus: 
Компилится, там runtime error: ничего не отматчено, поэтому `rx.Matches(text)[0]` вылетает. Судя по всему, .NET-овские регулярные выражения не поддерживают такой синтаксис.

---
Хотя нет, [поддерживают](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#grouping_constructs). Что-то не так с регуляркой?

---
Впрочем, PHP тоже ничего не находит: http://ideone.com/ZQpdp4

Answer (score 3):

А не слишком много ли у вас бэкслешей?

У меня вроде бы работает [так](http://ideone.com/16TsOq):

```
preg_match('/<span class="misspelt">(.*?)<\/span>/', $get, $match);
```